Was "The Princess and the Pea" written as satire?
"The Princess and the Pea" is a famous Hans Christian Andersen story about a princess proving herself to be a "real" princess by finding it deeply uncomfortable to sleep on a bed with a pea inside it, even if there are 20 mattresses on top of the pea.
What is the moral of this story? Is it poking fun at exaggerated upper-class sensibilities of comfort, in an essentially satirical way, or is it written more sincerely? There surely were stories of the time in Europe that sincerely promoted archaic concepts of royalty such as the divine right to rule, the whole concept of a "real" or "rightful" princess, and perhaps also the royal right to extreme comfort, and as a child I interpreted the story in that way, but my more sceptical and inquiring adult mind now wonders if perhaps the whole thing was meant to poke fun at overly sensitive, pampered princesses.
Wikipedia quotes literary critic Jack Zepes as saying that Andersen "had a mixed opinion of the upper classes, at the same time aspiring to them and scorning them". Facts of Andersen's life like this might be relevant in trying to ascertain authorial intent, which is one possible lens through which to answer this question. Another is to consider the historical context in which it was written: were stories of the time even allowed to satirise royalty, or is such a thing impossible to imagine for early 19th-century Scandinavia?

https://www.franklintwp.org/2020/04/10/the-princess-and-the-pea/ A simple yet pertinent article on this story as satire.

@Rand al'Thor  Or the story could be considered a joke, since probably nobody could believe that even a princess could really detect the lumpiness of one pea beneath 20 mattresses.  It sort of reminds me of a story where a warrior had underarm perspiration so strong it actually dissolved someone.

According to Hans Christian Andersen, the story is simply one he heard in his youth, now freely retold. He makes this claim in a foreword to the story, listing it as a Danish folk tale he heard as a child; so there doesn't seem any intention for it to be satire. However, there seems to be some debate about whether this attestation can be true. The Hans Christian Andersen version seems to be just a snippet of a longer tale, but told from the point of view of the prince and queen rather than the "princess" and her animal, as is usual - the original story being a gender-flipped version of Puss in Boots.
According to Maria Tatar's Annotated Hans Christian Andersen, Andersen claimed to have heard the story as a child. Apparently the story is unknown in Danish oral tradition, but does bear similarities to certain Swedish folk tales. In Zalka Csenge Virág's blog, she tracks down this original claim as being from the 1906 edition of Danske Studier, in an article by Georg Christensen:

Using Google Translate, that is:

As is known, H. C. Andersen has written forewords to his "Fairy Tales and Stories" (both the two volumes of 1862, and the three volumes of 1874) and has here provided information about the creation of some of them. For some, he cites Danish folk tales that he heard as a child and now freely reproduces as a source. These are the following (ordered by the year they were published):
1835. The Lighthouse. Little Claus and Big Claus. The Princess on the Pea.
1836. The Travelling Companion.
1838. The Wild Swans. The Garden of Paradise.
1842. The Pig Boy.
1855. Clumsy Hans.
1861. What one thinks is always right.
As you can see, usage has declined quite sharply over the years. However, a few of the older ones must be excluded. Andersen probably never heard "The Princess on the Pea." In any case, it is not found in any Danish record. It also looks more like an episode, an anecdote, than a fairy tale. Where does this princess come from, and why is she being tested?

Later on in the publication, Georg seems to have another stab at the origin of the story:

There are two more fairy tales, The Garden of Paradise and The Princess on the Pea, which Andersen claims to have heard as a child. However, there are no known Danish models for either of them. It is reasonable that impressions of what he has heard and read have merged somewhat in his memory.

He goes on to list several fairy tales (such as The Palace That Stood on Golden Pillars) from Sweden, Finland, Italy, etc which all feature the bed test, but in each case where the tested individual (usually a girl but sometimes a boy) is tipped off about the test by a clever animal (either a dog or a cat), and told to act as if they've had the worst night's sleep ever so as to win the prince (or princess). The common factor seems to be that in every case the rulers believe the test is a sure test for nobility, but in every case they are actually being fooled. Georg then tries to track down where the idea that sensitivity might indicate nobility comes from, noting several eastern (Greek, Persian, Magyar) anecdotes about extraordinarily sensitive people:

Timaeus tells of a Sybarite who developed a hernia from seeing some workers hoeing in a field. Another person he tells it to becomes ill from hearing the story. Another Sybarite (in Ælian, Variæ historiæ IX, 24) is striped all over his back from lying on a bed of rose petals. The anecdote is told in Ælian about Smindyrides, who already stood as a type of a Sybarite in Herodotus. Later the motif is attached to a historical person in Persia, namely King Shapur's queen Nadirah. She is wounded to the point of bleeding by a myrtle leaf lying in her bed. Baital Pacchisi no. 23 (Oesterley's ed.) tells of a man who could not sleep because a hair lying under the 7th mattress stabbed him in the back.

and deciding that it is in Indian stories where this idea was first used artistically; he tells of a story in Kathasaritsagara where it is asked which of a king's three wives was most sensitive, one who was wounded by a lotus leaf that fell from her ear into her lap, one who was burned by the moon's rays, and on who got a bruise on her hand when she heard the sound of a mortar far away. This he then follows through to European stories such as a story in L'elite Des Contes Du Sieur D'ouville (1680) of four women betting on who is the most delicate. Georg summarises:

As far as I can see, the development must have been as follows:
From ancient times there have been little anecdotes about the excessive susceptibility of pleasure-loving, refined people, "Sybarites", to sensory impressions. The Indians have enriched this motif by making the degree of sensitivity a kind of gauge of value. Since it is created by life habits, it will be an infallible characteristic of the noble, the prince or princess. The one whose body has been hardened by poverty or work will not have such sensitivity... But if sensitivity is a mark of status, it is quite reasonable that the prince who sets out to propose will only want the most sensitive. Similarly, Andersen's prince will only want a real princess. If she cannot legitimize herself in any other way, her sensitivity is tested by the queen at bedtime.
Undeniably there is a leap here, since, as mentioned, the one against whom the test is deliberately imposed is not at all sensitive or of high
burden — except in Andersen. But I still believe that this feature in the
Swedish texts must be traced back to oriental models... Undoubtedly, the Orient must be the home of such a motif. H. C. Andersen's "The Princess and the Pea" must be said to stand in the middle. He has the sensitive princess of the Easterners, and he has the consciously set test of the Swedes. Like the latter, he has isolated the motif without the connection with the helper-animal fairy tale, in which it occurs only in the North, and with almost super-Oriental imagination and whimsy he places 20 eiderdown duvets on top of 20 mattresses and the pea at the very bottom.

So, I suppose the exact interpretation of the Andersen version is a little up for debate. Either the princess really was super sensitive, in the same mould as the Indian stories; or she actually had a helper animal (or her own wits) that we don't see, as the story is from the point of view of the prince, who doesn't notice the cat in the original Swedish tales. And either Andersen intended to tell a faithful retelling of a folk story he heard in his youth (as he claims) but his memory caused it to end up much abbreviated and a good deal changed; or he intentionally made changes to it. Without any further evidence from Andersen it would be hard to guess his intent. The last lines of the story:

So the prince took her for his wife, for now he knew that he had a real princess; and the pea was put in the museum, where it may still be seen, if no one has stolen it.
There, that is a true story.

are perhaps a hint. For anyone familiar with the original fairytale, they will know that the prince was fooled; she isn't a real princess, she was simply doing what her cat or dog told her to say. So it's not really a true story at all; although all the particulars we were told are true, the parts that were missed out entirely change the meaning of the story. The story is the same, but means something quite different. In the same way that placing a pea in a museum makes it still just a pea, but also something completely different, an object to be admired. Or maybe I'm overthinking things!
